What exactly does the function objectGetProperty need in its third argument value "GValue"?
I am trying to compile the example from https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs/-/blob/main/video/gtk4/examples/gtksink.py . I need to write it in Haskell and I'm currently stuck on the paintable = gtksink.get_property('paintable') function written in Python. I've searched around and found objectGetProperty from the Gi-GObject library which seems like the one that I need. However I can't seem to get it to work because it asks me for a GValue of some kind in its third argument. I have tried to pass it a lot of stuff but nothing seems correct.
This is my code up so far:
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, OverloadedLabels, ImplicitParams #-}

import Control.Monad (void)
import System.Environment (getArgs, getProgName)

import Data.Int (Int32)
import qualified GHC.Foreign as GHC

import qualified GI.Gtk as Gtk
import qualified GI.Gdk as Gdk
import qualified GI.Gsk as Gsk
import qualified GI.Gio as Gio
import qualified GI.GObject as GObject
import qualified GI.Gst as Gst
import qualified GI.GLib as GLib
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.GI.Base

activate :: Gtk.Application -> IO ()
activate app = do

  pipeline <- Gst.pipelineNew (Just ("pippo"))
  
  gtksink <- Gst.elementFactoryMake "gtk4paintablesink" (Just ("pluto"))
  paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0


  player <- Gtk.videoNew
  Gtk.videoSetAutoplay player True
  file_to_play <- Gio.fileNewForPath ("D:/stack-projects/gtk-intro-twelve/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm")
  Gtk.videoSetFile player (Just (file_to_play))

  window <- new Gtk.ApplicationWindow [#application := app,
                                       #title := "Hello",
                                       #child := player]
  #setDefaultSize window 1427 1080
  #show window

main :: IO ()
main = do
  app <- new Gtk.Application [#applicationId := "haskell-gi.Gtk4.test",
                              On #activate (activate ?self)]

  -- If the application does not need to parse command line arguments
  -- just pass Nothing.
  args <- getArgs
  progName <- getProgName
  void $ #run app (Just $ progName : args)

It compiles with the errors:
D:\stack-projects\gtk-intro-twelve\app\Main.hs:46:16: error: [GHC-05617]
    * Could not solve: `Data.GI.Base.Overloading.CheckForAncestorType
                          (Maybe Gst.Element)
                          GObject.Object
                          (Data.GI.Base.Overloading.ParentTypes (Maybe Gst.Element))'
        arising from a use of `GObject.objectGetProperty'
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
      In the expression:
        do pipeline <- Gst.pipelineNew (Just ("pippo"))
           gtksink <- Gst.elementFactoryMake
                        "gtk4paintablesink" (Just ("pluto"))
           paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
           player <- Gtk.videoNew
           ....
      In an equation for `activate':
          activate app
            = do pipeline <- Gst.pipelineNew (Just ("pippo"))
                 gtksink <- Gst.elementFactoryMake
                              "gtk4paintablesink" (Just ("pluto"))
                 paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
                 ....
   |
46 |   paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

D:\stack-projects\gtk-intro-twelve\app\Main.hs:46:16: error: [GHC-39999]
    * No instance for `GObject (Maybe Gst.Element)'
        arising from a use of `GObject.objectGetProperty'
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
      In the expression:
        do pipeline <- Gst.pipelineNew (Just ("pippo"))
           gtksink <- Gst.elementFactoryMake
                        "gtk4paintablesink" (Just ("pluto"))
           paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
           player <- Gtk.videoNew
           ....
      In an equation for `activate':
          activate app
            = do pipeline <- Gst.pipelineNew (Just ("pippo"))
                 gtksink <- Gst.elementFactoryMake
                              "gtk4paintablesink" (Just ("pluto"))
                 paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
                 ....
   |
46 |   paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

D:\stack-projects\gtk-intro-twelve\app\Main.hs:46:62: error: [GHC-39999]
    * No instance for `Num GValue' arising from the literal `0'
    * In the third argument of `GObject.objectGetProperty', namely `0'
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
      In the expression:
        do pipeline <- Gst.pipelineNew (Just ("pippo"))
           gtksink <- Gst.elementFactoryMake
                        "gtk4paintablesink" (Just ("pluto"))
           paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
           player <- Gtk.videoNew
           ....
   |
46 |   paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0
   |                                                              ^

I have started from the https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi/blob/master/examples/Gtk4/gtk4-example.hs example, I'm trying to display a video through Gtk4.
I've tried looking online at the docs.gtk.org website, I looked at the GObject class and read something about having to first install properties before accessing them with install_properties and GParamSpecs but I'm not sure I'm on the right track. Do you mind explaining to me what I'm doing wrong?

I don't understand nothing about Haskel but you have to pass a Gvalue as third parameter. Create one using GObject.Value.init(). On python this works because the language bind initiates the Gvalue on attribuition.

Does get gtksink #paintable work?

@DanielWagner sadly no, it compiles with error * Type Maybe Gst.Element does not have any known attributes.

@Kripto I have found paramValueSetDefault from the module GI.GObject.Functions. It asks for a GParamSpec value type. I understand you are a python user but can you tell me what that is? I've searched for it but I still don't understand :(

Have you ever looked here? https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/concepts.html

An example of the implementation of properties in C can be found here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185115/22768315

If the parts of the API you need aren't available in the introspection data that gtk ships with, you may have to use the base operations a bit more manually. Take a look at Data.GI.Base.Properties, it may get you going in the right direction for that.

The line 46  paintable <- GObject.objectGetProperty gtksink "paintable" 0 has multiple issues.

The argument gtkSink is of type (Maybe Gst.Element) but
objectGetProperty :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsObject a) => a -> Text -> GValue -> m ()

expects something with a type in typeclass IsObject. Since Gst.Element is in that typeclass you can solve the first issue by pattern matching or by using fromJust.

The third argument needs to be a GValue. The type is defined in module Data.GI.Base.GValue. The module also provides functions to create a GValue for example
toGValue :: forall a m. (IsGValue a, MonadIO m) => a -> m GValue

Since Maybe Gst.Element is an element of the type class IsGValue (yes, with Maybe this time) I suggest you want to create a GValue using gtksink.

This is not an error but please note that GObject.objectGetProperty returns nothing but the unit. Therefore paintable :: () is not usefull by any means.


Here is the replacement for line 46:
case gtksink of
  Nothing -> error "elementFactoryMake wasn't able to create the sink."
  Just sink -> GObject.objectGetProperty sink "paintable" =<< toGValue gtksink


I think this answer nearly gives me what I need, but I don't understand one thing. In your replacement code the toGValue gtksink turns a value of type Maybe Gst.Element into GValue. This GValue is then passed to objectGetProperty .... Does that mean that this passed GValue is mutable?

There is no such thing as "mutable values" in haskell but there are effectfull functions.
The GValue returned by toGValue gtksink is under the hood a pointer. The pointer itself cannot mutate but each monad function
getting this GValue can in fact read and change the values the pointer is pointing to.
Note, that only monad functions can do such mutations. Thats why
objectGetProperty :: (HasCallStack, MonadIO m, IsObject a) => a -> Text -> GValue -> m () 
is returning m () instead of just ().

The reason I lost so many words here is, that in Haskell it is inprecise to ask the question whether a value is mutable or not. None of them are. The mutabilaty comes more from the fact, that all the functions do have a monadic return value. Not by the value itself.

Makes sense. Thanks for explaining. I misused the word mutable and I meant to ensure that GValue acts more like an IORef with some additional GLib functionalities.
