Populating dropdown with strings in GTK4
I have a GHashTable whose keys are strings.
GList *keylist = g_hash_table_get_keys (my_hash);

I want to populate a DropDown with the strings in keylist using a model.
In Gtk > DropDown I see methods such as set_factory, set_list_factory, and set_model, but I'm not able to put the pieces together to populate the dropdown.
In example columnview with strings gtk4 C someone thankfully posted an example for populating a column view from a model with five fields. That example is helpful, but seems complicated for populating a dropdown menu with strings.
Is a simple example or some guidance available for my use case? Thank you.

After many trials and errors, I was able to populate the dropdown with the following few lines:
guint hash_size;
gpointer key_array = g_hash_table_get_keys_as_array (hash, &hash_size); /* Get the keys, which are strings, as an array */
GtkStringList *stringlist = gtk_string_list_new (key_array); /* Create a new GtkStringList model from the array of strings. */
gtk_drop_down_set_model (GTK_DROP_DOWN(dropdown), G_LIST_MODEL(stringlist)); /* Set the model as the source for the dropdown menu. */

As so often happens, now that I have the code working, I better understand the API in Gtk > DropDown > set_model. A GtkStringList implements GListModel, which we can see from the former's hierarachy. Is there a way to know what classes implement GListModel? That would have reduced my research time.
Anyway, thanks to all for reading and responding.

There is actually a simpler solution for a dropdown with strings:
GtkWidget*
gtk_drop_down_new_from_strings (
  const char* const* strings
)

This example shows how this can be implemented:
GTK 4 drop down signal "activate" not working
Have fun programming.

Thanks for this. I'm looking for an implementation with a model as the entries in the hash can change. I'm working through the GObject tutorial. It's a bit difficult to follow, but we'll see how it goes. Again, thank you.

Perhaps this answer is helpful. Here I used the GObject tutorial. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185115/22768315
