How to add FileFilter to FileDialog GTK4
Could someone explain me, how to add FileFilter to FileDialog GTK4?
I think, I have a wrong decision, it's not working.
Ive created GTKFileFilter* object and trying to add it to GTKFileDialog* object:
GtkFileDialog* fileDialog=gtk_file_dialog_new();
GtkFileFilter* filefilter = gtk_file_filter_new();
gtk_file_filter_add_suffix(filefilter,"tsc");
gtk_file_filter_set_name(filefilter,"Simple");
gtk_file_dialog_set_filters(fileDialog,filefilter);

But gtk_file_dialog_set_filters() expect a GListModel* as second parameter, so I've got assertion:

Gtk-CRITICAL **: 09:44:48.986: gtk_file_dialog_set_filters: assertion
'filters == NULL || G_IS_LIST_MODEL (filters)' failed

How can I create a right filters?

I tried it out and here is my suggestion.
#include<gtk/gtk.h>


  GtkFileDialog *filedialog = gtk_file_dialog_new();

  GtkFileFilter* filefilter = gtk_file_filter_new();
  gtk_file_filter_add_suffix(filefilter,"txt");
  gtk_file_filter_set_name(filefilter,"Text");

  GtkFileFilter *filefilter1 = gtk_file_filter_new();
  gtk_file_filter_add_suffix(filefilter1,"c");
  gtk_file_filter_set_name(filefilter1,"c-file");

  GListStore* liststore = g_list_store_new (GTK_TYPE_FILE_FILTER);
  g_list_store_append(liststore, filefilter);
  g_list_store_append(liststore, filefilter1);

  gtk_file_dialog_set_filters(filedialog,G_LIST_MODEL(liststore));

  gtk_file_dialog_open(filedialog,GTK_WINDOW(window),NULL,NULL,NULL);

The implementation of a list model can also be found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77759424/22768315
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185115/22768315
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77619798/22768315
Regards

Just create a GListModel and insert the filter you created into it, then pass it as a parameter to gtk_file_dialog_set_filters(). You can use a GListStore.
GListStore* liststore = g_list_store_new (GtkFileFilter)
g_list_store_append(liststore, filefilter)
gtk_file_dialog_set_filters(fileDialog, liststore);


Could you tell me, where can I looking for a full list of GListModels implementation?

I have a compile error:
error: expected expression before 'GtkFileFilter'
GListStore* list_store = g_list_store_new (GtkFileFilter);
