How can I make g_list_store_append know in which GtkColumnView append the string in gtk4
This code shows how I created the column view:
GListStore *store = g_list_store_new (GTK_TYPE_STRING_OBJECT);
GtkSelectionModel *selection = GTK_SELECTION_MODEL(gtk_single_selection_new (G_LIST_MODEL(store)));
GtkWidget *view = gtk_column_view_new (selection);
// begin col1:
GtkListItemFactory *factory = gtk_signal_list_item_factory_new ();
g_signal_connect (factory, "setup", G_CALLBACK (cb_setup_col1), NULL);
g_signal_connect (factory, "bind", G_CALLBACK (cb_bind_col1), NULL);
GtkColumnViewColumn *column1 = gtk_column_view_column_new ("Archivo", factory);
gtk_column_view_append_column (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (view), column1);
// end col1
// begin col2:
GtkColumnViewColumn *column2 = gtk_column_view_column_new ("Formato", factory);
gtk_column_view_append_column (GTK_COLUMN_VIEW (view), column2);
// end col2

g_autoptr(GtkStringObject) strobj1 = gtk_string_object_new ("str_for_col1");
g_autoptr(GtkStringObject) strobj2 = gtk_string_object_new ("str_for_col2");
g_list_store_append (store, strobj1);
g_list_store_append (store, strobj2);

//...
void cb_setup_col1 (GtkSignalListItemFactory *self, GtkListItem *list_item, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_label_new ("");
    gtk_list_item_set_child (list_item, label);
}

void cb_bind_col1 (GtkSignalListItemFactory *self, GtkListItem *list_item, gpointer user_data)
{
    GtkStringObject *strobj = gtk_list_item_get_item (list_item);
    GtkWidget *label = gtk_list_item_get_child (list_item);
    gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL(label), gtk_string_object_get_string (strobj));
}

The thing is that I realize that I have one model with the type string for both columns, not like gtk_list_store_set which I can tell the position to insert the string. Any ideas about how to insert strobj2 as item for the second column?

In order to create a column view with several columns, this should already be taken into account in the ListStore.
For example like this:
#define CAPITAL_TYPE_ITEM (capital_item_get_type())
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (CapitalItem, capital_item, CAPITAL, ITEM, GObject)

struct _CapitalItem
{
    GObject parent_instance;
    const char *name;
    const char *country;
    const char *founded;
    const char *population;
    const char *area;
};

struct _CapitalItemClass
{
    GObjectClass parent_class;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE (CapitalItem, capital_item, G_TYPE_OBJECT)

static void capital_item_init(CapitalItem *item)
{
}

static void capital_item_class_init(CapitalItemClass *class)
{
}

static CapitalItem * capital_item_new(const char *name,
                const char *country,
                const char *founded,
                const char *population,
                const char *area )
{
    CapitalItem  *item = g_object_new(CAPITAL_TYPE_ITEM, NULL);
    item->name = g_strdup(name);
    item->country = g_strdup(country);
    item->founded = g_strdup(founded);
    item->population = g_strdup(population);
    item->area = g_strdup(area);
    return item;
}

// a funktion that creates a GListModel with capital_item  objects
GListModel * create_capital_model(void)
{
    GListStore *store = g_list_store_new(G_TYPE_OBJECT);
    g_list_store_append(store, capital_item_new("Washington,D.C.","USA","1790","712,816","177"));
    g_list_store_append(store, capital_item_new("London","Britain","43","8,799,800","1,572.03"));
    g_list_store_append(store, capital_item_new("Paris","France","3rd c. BC","2,161,000","105"));
    g_list_store_append(store, capital_item_new("Berlin","Germany","13th century","3,850,809","891.3"));
    g_list_store_append(store, capital_item_new("Rome","Italy","753 BC","2,860,009","1,285"));
    return G_LIST_MODEL(store);
}

Furthermore, a factory is needed for each column.
A complete example can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77759424/22768315
How an entry selected with the mouse can be determined and changed is shown here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77619798/22768315
One option for sorting is shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78185115/22768315
Have fun continuing to code

Ok. I understand a bit about your code. But, how can mimic the same efect from gtk_list_store_get to grab n position string. For example, in your code, how to get France?

Access should always be via the GListStore. There are various functions for this.  g_list_store_insert_sorted;  g_list_store_insert; g_list_store_find_with_equal_func

Thanks for the input. This widget is a real challange. I'll wait for someone with alternate solution.

Marked as accepted answer because seems this method is most apropiate.
